# How can I get JSON data out of a web page and parse it in Excel VBA

Tags: json, excel, asp.net-web-api, vba

My company has a web service that we use to keep track of some information.  They have built an API that allows us to get information out of it.  My group is trying to do the same.  However, the other groups have all used C# to accomplish this, and the development level of this team isn't higher than that of Excel VBA.  What I need to do:

1. Go to a known URL http://service.company.com/Group=1
2. Get the JSON result that appears on the screen into VBA
3. Translate the JSON to readable human - [This part seems to have been solved here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627652/parsing-json-in-excel-vba)

The rest of the code around what I need to do, I can handle.  I'm hoping there is a JSON reader built into VBA that I can leverage for part 3.  Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
I figured out how to get JSON information out of the web page, there was some user/password authentication required in order to get that.  So that is part 1 and 2 done.  I'm working on Part 3.  The JSON information seems to be coming out in this pattern:

```
[{"Column1":value1,"Column2":value2},
{"Column1":value1,"Column2":value2}]
```

Comment: Are you only able to get the data in JSON format or is it possible to get them in XML as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON in Excel VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627652/parsing-json-in-excel-vba)

Comment: It's only JSON unfortunately.

The JSON part may be useful, the getting the data in JSON form in VBA doesn't appear to be in that solution

Comment: @legendjr please post a snippet of the JSON you have, if it is a sort of table-like data, then take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34275183/2165759).

Comment: Added some information in the edit.  I appreciate the help.