# Parse JSON on Excel (2003-2013)

Tags: json, vba, excel, feed

I'm currently trying to get a refreshable JSON feed into Excel off a link. I've come across code to assist me on another [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34275183/write-large-collection-object-parsed-from-json-to-excel-range) but when run, it generates an error

```
Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Unspecified error) on
"strMarkerQuot = Mid(CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib").GUID, 2, 36)".
```

Could I get assistance on either executing this code as is or any other method of parsing or extracting data off a cell (So far only managed to get the full JSON written to a cell)

This is the link to the [JSON feed](https://apilayer.net/api/live?access_key=4429e7caecf213b559496b1548f5f529&currencies=EUR,USD,AUD,BRL,CAD,CNY,CZK,DKK,XCD,EGP,HKD,HUF,INR,JPY,MYR,NZD,NOK,PLN,SGD,ZAR,SEK,CHF,THB,TRY,AED,BHD,BBD,IDR,ILS,JMD,JOD,KES,KWD,MUR,MAD,OMR,PKR,PHP,QAR,RUB,SAR,KRW,LKR,TWD,TTD,TND,BWP,BGN,CLP,COP,CRC,HRK,DOP,FJD,GMD,GTQ,ISK,MXN,RON,VND,PEN,ARS,BAM,BDT,BMD,BND,BOB,BSD,BZD,KYD,LBP,MOP,NAD,NPR,RSD,UAH&source=GBP&format=1) if required.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim strJsonString As String
    Dim arrResult() As Variant

    ' download
    strJsonString = DownloadJson("https://apilayer.net/api/live?access_key=4429e7caecf213b559496b1548f5f529&currencies=EUR,USD,AUD,BRL,CAD,CNY,CZK,DKK,XCD,EGP,HKD,HUF,INR,JPY,MYR,NZD,NOK,PLN,SGD,ZAR,SEK,CHF,THB,TRY,AED,BHD,BBD,IDR,ILS,JMD,JOD,KES,KWD,MUR,MAD,OMR,PKR,PHP,QAR,RUB,SAR,KRW,LKR,TWD,TTD,TND,BWP,BGN,CLP,COP,CRC,HRK,DOP,FJD,GMD,GTQ,ISK,MXN,RON,VND,PEN,ARS,BAM,BDT,BMD,BND,BOB,BSD,BZD,KYD,LBP,MOP,NAD,NPR,RSD,UAH&source=GBP&format=1")

    ' process
    arrResult = ConvertJsonToArray(strJsonString)

    ' output
    Output Sheets(1), arrResult

End Sub

Function DownloadJson(strUrl As String) As String

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", strUrl
        .Send
        If .Status <> 200 Then
            Debug.Print .Status
            Exit Function
        End If
        DownloadJson = .responseText
    End With

End Function


Function ConvertJsonToArray(strJsonString As String) As Variant

    Dim strCnt As String
    Dim strMarkerQuot As String
    Dim arrUnicode() As String
    Dim arrQuots() As String
    Dim arrRows() As String
    Dim arrProps() As String
    Dim arrTokens() As String
    Dim arrHeader() As String
    Dim arrColumns() As Variant
    Dim arrColumn() As Variant
    Dim arrTable() As Variant
    Dim j As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lngMaxRowIdx As Long
    Dim lngMaxColIdx As Long
    Dim lngPrevIdx As Long
    Dim lngFoundIdx As Long
    Dim arrProperty() As String
    Dim strPropName As String
    Dim strPropValue As String

    strCnt = Split(strJsonString, "{")(1)
    strCnt = Split(strCnt, "}")(0)

    strMarkerQuot = Mid(CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib").GUID, 2, 36)
    strCnt = Replace(strCnt, "\\", "\")
    strCnt = Replace(strCnt, "\""", strMarkerQuot)
    strCnt = Replace(strCnt, "\/", "/")
    strCnt = Replace(strCnt, "\b", Chr(8))
    strCnt = Replace(strCnt, "\f", Chr(12))
    strCnt = Replace(strCnt, "\n", vbLf)
    strCnt = Replace(strCnt, "\r", vbCr)
    strCnt = Replace(strCnt, "\t", vbTab)

    arrUnicode = Split(strCnt, "\u")
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrUnicode)
        arrUnicode(i) = ChrW(CLng("&H" & Left(arrUnicode(i), 4))) & Mid(arrUnicode(i), 5)
    Next
    strCnt = Join(arrUnicode, "")

    arrQuots = Split(strCnt, """")
    ReDim arrTokens(UBound(arrQuots) \ 2)
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrQuots) Step 2
        arrTokens(i \ 2) = Replace(arrQuots(i), strMarkerQuot, """")
        arrQuots(i) = "%" & i \ 2
    Next

    strCnt = Join(arrQuots, "")
    strCnt = Replace(strCnt, " ", "")

    arrRows = Split(strCnt, "},{")
    lngMaxRowIdx = UBound(arrRows)
    For j = 0 To lngMaxRowIdx
        lngPrevIdx = -1
        arrProps = Split(arrRows(j), ",")
        For i = 0 To UBound(arrProps)
            arrProperty = Split(arrProps(i), ":")
            strPropName = arrProperty(0)
            If Left(strPropName, 1) = "%" Then strPropName = arrTokens(Mid(strPropName, 2))
            lngFoundIdx = GetArrayItemIndex(arrHeader, strPropName)
            If lngFoundIdx = -1 Then
                ReDim arrColumn(lngMaxRowIdx)
                If lngPrevIdx = -1 Then
                    ArrayAddItem arrHeader, strPropName
                    lngPrevIdx = UBound(arrHeader)
                    ArrayAddItem arrColumns, arrColumn
                Else
                    lngPrevIdx = lngPrevIdx + 1
                    ArrayInsertItem arrHeader, lngPrevIdx, strPropName
                    ArrayInsertItem arrColumns, lngPrevIdx, arrColumn
                End If
            Else
                lngPrevIdx = lngFoundIdx
            End If
            strPropValue = arrProperty(1)
            If Left(strPropValue, 1) = "%" Then strPropValue = arrTokens(Mid(strPropValue, 2))
            arrColumns(lngPrevIdx)(j) = strPropValue
        Next
    Next
    lngMaxColIdx = UBound(arrHeader)
    ReDim arrTable(lngMaxRowIdx + 1, lngMaxColIdx)
    For i = 0 To lngMaxColIdx
        arrTable(0, i) = arrHeader(i)
    Next
    For j = 0 To lngMaxRowIdx
        For i = 0 To lngMaxColIdx
            arrTable(j + 1, i) = arrColumns(i)(j)
        Next
    Next

    ConvertJsonToArray = arrTable

End Function

Sub Output(objSheet As Worksheet, arrCells() As Variant)

    With objSheet
        .Select
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), Cells(UBound(arrCells, 1) + 1, UBound(arrCells, 2) + 1)).Value = arrCells
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
    With ActiveWindow
        .SplitColumn = 0
        .SplitRow = 1
        .FreezePanes = True
    End With

End Sub

Function GetArrayItemIndex(arrElements, varTest)
    For GetArrayItemIndex = 0 To SafeUBound(arrElements)
        If arrElements(GetArrayItemIndex) = varTest Then Exit Function
    Next
    GetArrayItemIndex = -1
End Function

Sub ArrayAddItem(arrElements, varElement)
    ReDim Preserve arrElements(SafeUBound(arrElements) + 1)
    arrElements(UBound(arrElements)) = varElement
End Sub

Sub ArrayInsertItem(arrElements, lngIndex, varElement)
    Dim i As Long
    ReDim Preserve arrElements(SafeUBound(arrElements) + 1)
    For i = UBound(arrElements) To lngIndex + 1 Step -1
        arrElements(i) = arrElements(i - 1)
    Next
    arrElements(i) = varElement
End Sub

Function SafeUBound(arrTest)
    On Error Resume Next
    SafeUBound = -1
    SafeUBound = UBound(arrTest)
End Function
```

Comment: Where is your code? Please edit your question and post the code.

Comment: The code is on  the linked page, it's essentially the same as the answer posted there with a different link, but will adjust the question in a sec

Comment: so, you have the <2000 character result sitting in an Excel cell and all you need to do is get the rates out of it?

Comment: `CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib").GUID` no longer works because of security reasons. You can try other approaches outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7031347/7296893).

Comment: I have a simple solution for you -- I'll post in a couple mins

Comment: wait. Is the access key genuine? you shouldn't post any credential-related information in your question, to protect your privacy.

Comment: It is, currently on a cheap sub for the testing phase. Promptly reset after this was sorted out. Thanks for the heads up tho, would've been easy to miss that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON string is very basic.  Rather than using complicated objects and collections, we can just parse it will simple text functions.

Function `extractRates` will run as-is (just enter the name of a blank worksheet in Constant: `outputSheet`).

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub extractRates()

    Const url = "https://apilayer.net/api/live?access_key=4429e7caecf213b559496b1548f5" & _
        "f529&currencies=EUR,USD,AUD,BRL,CAD,CNY,CZK,DKK,XCD,EGP,HKD,HUF,INR,JPY,MYR," & _
        "NZD,NOK,PLN,SGD,ZAR,SEK,CHF,THB,TRY,AED,BHD,BBD,IDR,ILS,JMD,JOD,KES,KWD,MUR," & _
        "MAD,OMR,PKR,PHP,QAR,RUB,SAR,KRW,LKR,TWD,TTD,TND,BWP,BGN,CLP,COP,CRC,HRK,DOP,FJD," & _
        "GMD,GTQ,ISK,MXN,RON,VND,PEN,ARS,BAM,BDT,BMD,BND,BOB,BSD,BZD,KYD,LBP,MOP,NAD,NPR," & _
        "RSD,UAH&source=GBP&format=1"
    'alternate url: (much shorter and returns "all 167 from GBP")
    'Const url = "https://apilayer.net/api/live?" & _
        "access_key=4429e7caecf213b559496b1548f5f529&source=GBP&format=1"

    Const stripLeft = """quotes"":{" 'strip everything up to & including this
    Const stripRight = "}" 'strip everything after & including this
    Const outputSheet = "Sheet1" 'output worksheet
    Const rowOffset = 1 'start output on this row

    Dim json As String, json_orig As String, arr, x As Long
    json_orig = getHTTP(url) 'retrieve json
    json = json_orig 'for debugging without reloading

    'strip ends
    x = InStr(json, stripLeft) + Len(stripLeft)
    json = Right(json, Len(json) - x)
    x = InStr(json, stripRight)
    json = Left(json, x - 1)

    'remove whitespace
    json = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(json) '(worksheet trim grabs middle blanks)
    json = Replace(json, vbLf, "") 'remove Line Feeds (some API will have vbCR's too)
    json = Replace(json, """", "") 'remove quotation marks
    json = Replace(json, " ", "") 'remove single spaces

    'String is now the string is like: "GBPEUR:1.127663,GBPUSD:1.394759,...": split it by comma
    arr = Split(json, ",")

    'confirm & clear cells
    If MsgBox(UBound(arr) & " quotes found." & vbLf & vbLf & "Worksheet `" & outputSheet & _
        "` will be cleared.", vbOKCancel + vbExclamation, "Delete Existing Data?") <> vbOK Then Exit Sub
    Sheets(outputSheet).Cells.ClearContents

    'dump array into rows
    For x = 0 To UBound(arr) - 1
        Sheets(outputSheet).Range("A" & x + rowOffset) = arr(x)
    Next x

    'text to columns to split on colon
    Sheets(outputSheet).Range("A" & rowOffset & ":A" & x + rowOffset).TextToColumns _
        Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, Other:=True, OtherChar:=":"
    Range("A1").Select
    Debug.Print "Done!"

End Sub

Public Function getHTTP(ByVal url As String) As String
'equivalent to Excel's WEBSERVICE function
    Dim encResp() As Byte, xmlHTTP As Object
    Set xmlHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP") 'create XML/HTTP object
    xmlHTTP.Open "GET", url, False 'initialize GET request
    xmlHTTP.send 'send request to remote server
    encResp = xmlHTTP.responseBody 'receive raw (encoded) response
    Set xmlHTTP = Nothing 'always clean up after yourself!
    getHTTP = StrConv(encResp, vbUnicode) 'return decoded response
End Function
```

`getHTTP` work like Excel 2016's `WEBSERVICE` function: it takes any URL and returns the code behind it, whether HTML, XML, JSON, CSV, etc...

Procedure `extractRates` strips the beginning and end from the json string, removes unneeded characters, splits it into an array, and dumps the array on to the `outputSheet` where `TextToColumns` finishes it up.

Imncidentally, you can shorten your URL considerably by returning "all" rates compared to a country with [this link](https://apilayer.net/api/live?access_key=4429e7caecf213b559496b1548f5f529&source=GBP&format=1).

<sub>API Documentation [here](https://currencylayer.com/documentation).</sub>